# How to convert from std::string to templated T, or maybe check first if it is possible?

Tags: c++, c++11

How to convert from std::string to templated T, or maybe check first if it is possible?

I have template function on type T. There is input std::string,
and I need to convert the string to T. For example if the string is "42",
then:

```
1) if T is float then convert to float with value 42.0f
2) if T is int then convert to int with value 42
3) if T is string then convert to string "42"
4) if T is user-defined type then look for a constructor of T that takes string
```

Comment: @remyabel Not sure what you mean... I need to first of all check if I can convert from string to T, and if so, then do it. That is all.

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast` comes to mind

Comment: @user Yeah I got it backwards, ignore my comment.

Comment: @arne: Yes, although lexical cast uses `operator<<` and `operator>>`, it won't use a conversion constructor taking `std::string`

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you think you need the function to be a function *template*.  Can you explain?

Comment: @JohnDibling this is simplified part of a bigger problem I am working on. But trust me I do need this :)

Comment: Can you show us how you'd like to use this? It matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
T convert(const string& s) { return T(s); }

template<>
string convert<string>(const string& s) { return s; }

template<>
int convert<int>(const string& s) { return stoi(s); }
```

Other specializations are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Specializations for function templates should be avoided whenever possible, rather use overloading>

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Please show me how to overload on the return type alone.

Comment: Seems like a nice solution @IgorTandetnik

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Use helper functions with two arguments one of which to select correct overload.

Comment: @Nawaz what do you mean?

Comment: The specialisation for `string` is redundant, as it does the same thing as the generic version. (You could perhaps return `const string&` to allow the copy to be avoided in some situations.)

Comment: `template<typename T> struct unused {}; template<typename T> T convert_helper( const string& s, unused<T>&& )` is your helper.  `template<typename T> T convert( const string& s ) { return convert_helper( s, unused<T>() ); }` then does dispatching to `convert_helper`.  Add in conversion capabilities to `unused<T>()` for more magic.

Comment: @user3111311: See the above comment by Yakk!

Comment: @Nawaz that is kinda ugly. The original post solution seems cleaner.

Comment: @user3111311: The original solution might turn into disaster too easily.

Comment: @Nawaz Why use rvalue reference? And what is this supposed to do: convert_helper( s, unused<T>() ); In general I am not sure what unused struct is used for there.

Comment: Search for "why function template specialization is bad". Or read this : [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: how is specialization or template deduction occuring based on return type

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum It doesn't. The caller has to specify the type they want to convert to, as in `convert<int>("42")`. I figured that's what the OP wanted, based on his or her problem statement that conspicuously lacked any example code.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer this solution over boost::lexical_cast?

Comment: I don't believe `lexical_cast` satisfies "look for a constructor of T that takes string" part of your problem statement. It relies on `operator>>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This already exists; it's called [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main()
{
   const std::string s1 = "abc",
                     s2 = "123",
                     s3 = "45.6";

   const int   i = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s2);
   std::cout << i << ' ';

   const float f = boost::lexical_cast<float>(s3);
   std::cout << f << ' ';

   try {
      boost::lexical_cast<int>(s1);  // can't do this!
   }
   catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast&) {
      std::cout << '!' << '\n';
   }
}

// Output: 123 45.6 !
```

#### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a58af30d7d6705db)

Comment: Well it is not that simple, so I wonder why you post at all if you don't provide examples.

Comment: @user3111311: There you go.

Comment: One proviso: this doesn't fit *exactly* with what the OP specified. It requires an `operator>>` for the type, not just a constructor for that type that takes a string. Granted, having `operator>>` is generally preferable, but still a difference worth noting.

Comment: @Jerry: Yeah, to be fair, this was kinda lazy as a post but I'm a sucker for _sweet sweet repz_. I actually implement my own `lexical_cast` that uses the various direct conversion functions for integral types through a suite of specialisations, falling back on `boost::lexical_cast` for the base case.

Comment: Isn't it a better solution to use templates as other suggested? That way it seems I have more control over the conversions. Plus it is easy to add new specializations.

Comment: @user3111311: This _does_ "use templates". But, yes, as I said, that's what I do in real code too. This however is an easier solution that requires no "re-inventing" if you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see how any specialization or template deduction can occur based on return type, so the lvalue would need to be passed to the convert function

Also, while it might be desirable to use specialization, converting 'any type` seems to require templates

something like this works:

```
template <typename T>
void convert(T& lhs, const std::string& s) { lhs= T(s); }

template<>
void convert<int>(int& lhs, const std::string& s) { lhs= std::stoi(s); }

 ... (all other conversions)
```

Tested with:

```
int x;
convert(x,"31");
```

Comment: +1: We don't _know_ that this is what he's trying to do, but if he is then this is the way.

Comment: What do you think about lexical_cast?

Comment: Is this better approach than Igor's solution above?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generic template to cover 3 and 4:

```
template <typename T>
T to(std::string const & s) {
    return T(s);
}
```

then specialise it for types that need special conversions:

```
template <>
float to<float>(std::string const & s) {
    return std::stof(s);
}
```

It should be possible to use SFINAE to allow conversion to all numeric types via `stringstream`; but that's beyond my template-wrangling comfort zone, and left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Either `void` or `return` is wrong. They don't really go together.

Comment: Isn't this the same as @IgorTandetnik suggested?

Comment: @user3111311: Indeed, we both wrote very similar answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T,typename=void>
struct convert_string_to : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct convert_string_to<
  T,
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<std::string const&, T>::value>::type
> : std::true_type {
  T operator()( std::string const& src ) const { return src; }
};
template<typename I>
struct convert_string_to<
  I,
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<I>::value>::type
> : std::true_type {
  I operator()( std::string const& src ) const {
    // TODO: insert code to convert `src` to an integer
  };
};
template<typename I>
struct convert_string_to<
  F,
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<F>::value>::type
> : std::true_type {
  F operator()( std::string const& src ) const {
    // TODO: insert code to convert `src` to a floating point
  };
};
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< convert_string_to<T>::value, T >::type
convert_string( std::string const& str ) {
  return convert_string_to<T>()(str);
}
```

I would, however, consider returning a `std::optional<T>` or `std::expected<T>` equivalent (both are proposed for future standards, but their design is fully supported in C++11) instead of a `T`, to allow for errors to occur without using exceptions.

Also, need move-construct version.

In this case, overload resolution fails on `convert_string` if the type does not work, and it works for all integral types and all floating point types (not just `int` and `float` or some fixed set).

Comment: how is specialization or template deduction occuring based on return type

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum you use it as `convert_string<int>(s)`.  Alternatively, you can do `struct do_convert_later{ std::string const&s; template<typename T> operator T()const{ return convert_string<T>(s);} };` and have `do_convert_later convert( std::string const& s ) { return {s}; }` if you don't like specifying the type.